# Determine second degree polynomial by least squares method

Tags: polynomials, approximation

Determine the polynomial of the second degree that approximates by the method of least squares in the following function, at the interval [0,5, 1,5].

$f(x)=\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}$

I´ve done least squares before using the point table, 
but now all i have is a function! How can i solve this?

Comment: For a second degree polynomial, you would need three points to obtain the three coefficients - what about using the end points and mid point of interval?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan It is unlikely that this method will provide the LS approximation of $f(x)$

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Okay, but how do i turn the coefficients into the polynomial?

Comment: Please refer to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your polynomial to be
$$P(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$$

Now, the error in approximation is defined as

$$E(P, f) = \left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b(P - f)^2dx\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$

Hence, your task is to find $a,b,c$ to minimise

$$I = \int_{0.5}^{1.5}\left(ax^2+bx+c-\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2dx$$

Now, to solve for $a,b,c$, you will need to solve the system

$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial I}{\partial b} = \frac{\partial I}{\partial c} = 0$$